# Glassfish warnings : Avertissement: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I use NetBeansIDE  7.0.1 with Glassfish 3.1 and for a project with EJB and JPA for the presentation and the MySQL database.
all works fine but whenever I get the following warnings:

```
    Avertissement: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@11bfacc].
    Avertissement: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@11bfacc] from index [0] 
    Avertissement: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@24d165] from index [1]
```

What Glassfish configuration can solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.